# Ordering a Map Logic

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, caching

I am having some trouble trying to solve or come up with a solution for a task I have to do.

I am trying to make a ranking system for my application. My main cache data structure is as follows:

```
Map<String user, Profile personsProfile>
```

The profile has a number of values - one of which is a numeric value I want to order by. The profile class has a custom comparator:

```
public static class CompareHots implements Comparator<Profile> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Profile o1, Profile o2) {
        return ((Integer) o1.getHots()).compareTo((Integer) o2.getHots());
    }
}
```

So as it stands, given a list `(map.values())` I am able to order the profile objects, but I don't have a way to tie it back to the user. So for example if i wanted to find the ranking for profile john i could do

```
Collections.sort(cache.values(), new Profile.CompareHots)
```

however although this would be quick, i would then need to undo all of the good work by iterating over the whole list checking for `if(profile.getUserId().equals("John")` and then returning the index.

Does anyone know a better way i could go about solving this problem?

Thanks

Comment: I don't get why you try to sort the profiles. As of your description, you always like to find a profile for a given user. Could you provide the main use case what you try to achieve? But not in terms of code or implementation, but in terms of **what** to do.

Comment: the users need to be ranked in order of there profile hot value - from 1 -> total number of users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your use case correctly, you like to find users sorted by their profile ranking. How about changing the mapping from:

```
Map<String user, Profile personsProfile>
```

to:

```
Map<Profile personsProfile, String user>
```

instead? Now every implementation of [SortedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) will do what you need. When iteration over the keys (which are profiles), you get them in the order as provided by your [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). Than use the profile and lookup the user. That's it.

Comment: lol it was so simple yet i struggled to do it myself sigh! thanks for a great solution

Answer (score 0):

Probably [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) will help you:

```java
SortedMap<String, Profile> ranking = new TreeMap<>(customComparator);
...
String user = "John"; 
int rank = ranking.headMap(user, true).size();
```

Comment: I don't think it will help him, because the TreeMap is ordered but you cannot get an absolute position of an item in it, and it is backed up as with a tree. Getting the entries as an array is no more optimal than his existing idea.

Comment: A `TreeMap` is a `SortedMap` which is sorted by keys and not values. This won't help at all.

Comment: @Harmlezz Truly, my carelessness. If to try sorting map [by values](http://hmkcode.com/sorting-java-map-by-key-value/)?

Comment: Have a look at my answer. I think switching `key <=> value` in the map would do the job.